# How to cycle through an array of pictures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to have a Snapchat story-like feature where an array of pictures is displayed for a set period of seconds and than go back to the previous navigation.

Something like the following:

```js
if (props.length > 0) {    
    let timeout;
    if (props.length - 1 === index) {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        navigation.goBack()
    }

    if (props[index].image) {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            setIndex(index + 1)
        }, 3000)
        return <Image source={{ uri: props[index].image }} style={{ flex: 1 }} />
    }
}
```

But, this is showing unpredictable results.

Comment: Although it's kind of off-topic, it may fit the title. For picture loop display, you can use related libs like [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper), which also provide `autoplay` option

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might wanna use `setInterval` instead. eg. in codesandbox [here](https://mgzk3.csb.app/)